# Unexpected character error in JQuery ajax function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have the 'unexpected character error' problem, my Jquery ajax code looks like that:

```
 function test(){
        if(true){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'test.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                godot: 'godot',
                jobadze: 'jobadze'
            },
            success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert("Error Status: "+textStatus+"\nMessage: "+errorThrown);
            }
        });
```

and this is the php code:

```
<?php
echo 'test';
?>
```

it should alert "test", but it calls error. What is going on?

Comment: remove `dataType` from your request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning any JSON. You returning text but you've specified in the AJAX that it will return json.

You have: `dataType: 'json',`

You could change the `dataType: 'text',` if you will always be returning text

or in your php change `echo 'test';` to `echo json_encode('test');`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

You wrote `dataType: 'json'`, so the PHP script is required to return valid JSON. Since you're not, the it gets an error when it tries to parse the response as JSON, and reports that error.

You should use `json_encode`:

```
<?php
echo json_encode('test');
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

*it should alert "test", but it calls error. What is going on?*

Reason for this is your `dataType : "json"` in `$.ajax()` method which expects the response from serverside should be a `json`, which is not the case because that is just a simple text string nothing else, so what could you do:

1. Either remove the `dataType` or change the `dataType: "text"`
2. Or do a `json_encode('string')` at your serverside.

As you asked in your question

### *It should alert "test"*,

so you can skip the #2 and do this:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'test.php',
        dataType: 'text',
        data: {
            godot: 'godot',
            jobadze: 'jobadze'
        },
        success: function(data){
            alert(data); // will alert "test".
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
             alert("Error Status: "+textStatus+"\nMessage: "+errorThrown);
        }
    });
```

### *but it calls error*

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'test.php',
        dataType: 'json', //<----because of this
```

See `json` is a `{key : value}` pair js object and from your `php` you are just echoing a string not a object.